# Introductory book on knot theory in smooth category

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

I know several introductory books on knot theory in PL category, but I'm not familiar with PL topology.

So I'm looking for introductory books on knot theory in smooth category. Could you recommend some books?

Comment: For knotted circles in the 3-sphere, [the PL category and the smooth category are basically equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297894/how-is-pl-knot-theory-related-to-smooth-knot-theory?rq=1). So you could read your PL book and substitute the word "smooth" wherever you see the word "PL".